# Android Studio not closing brackets

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem code editor of Android Studio version 3.4.1. After a restart, the Studio stopped closing the braces while editing Java files.

[image]

I have checked and confirmed that Studio closes braces in XML files.

Attached is the screenshot.

Comment: Try to rename the user settings folder (C:\Users\username\AndroidStudio3.4). Restart AS. Wait 1-2 minutes to finish. Then open project. Any change?

Comment: @Biswapriyo After posting here I went back and deleted the folder, in my case `~/.AndroidStudio3.4`, which resolved the issue. I could not come back here and update the post.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Settings > Editor > General > Smart Keys (or just search for smart keys or "Insert paired brackets" in the Settings) and make sure that "Insert paired brackets" is checked.

It it is, try disabling it and re-enabling.

[Here is a screenshot of "Insert paired brackets"'s position in Smart Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKNZd.png)